# Return a value to a cell in google spreadsheet with an onEdit trigger

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm basically trying to make a script that when cell `C4` is changed or edited then it will return the variable "date" to cell `L4`.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy/MM/dd");
  var cellAddress = e.range.getA1Notation();

  if ( CellAdress === 'C4' ) {
    var range = sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('L4');
    var nrange = sheet.setActiveRange(range);
    nrange = date
  }
}
```

I know that the last part doesn't work, but I can't get my head around how to properly use the functions, been searching for a while but can't find anything related precisely to making the function change the cell.

Comment: Because variable names are case-sensitive, 'cellAdress' is not the same as 'CellAddress'. 'CellAdress' is undefined and therefore can't be equal to 'C4'. You get the  range via sheet.getRange(A1Notation) and set the value in a single cell by calling range.setValue(value)

Comment: @AntonDementiev Thanks for pointing out the obvious that I couldn't see. I've tried applying your fixes however it still does not work. I'm starting to pull hair out my head cuz I can't figure out which is wrong. Although I think it might have something to do with this line: var cellAddress = sheet.getRange.getA1Notation();

Comment: You will probably benefit from using a pen and paper to describe your script (or otherwise explaining it to an inanimate object in profuse detail). Go through piece by piece (periods and control characters are good piece separators) and describe what that piece is: a primitive value? A class instance? A method of a class object? A variable that references a primitive or a class object? Reviewing the Apps Script reference documentation is an excellent idea as well (including pages that talk about event objects provided to simple trigger functions such as `onEdit`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Write new Date() string to L4 when C4 is edited on any Sheet

Please note this function is called whenever any edit is made on any sheet.  Since this function does not specify a sheet, then an edit of cell C4 on any sheet will set the value of L4 on on that sheet.  So I would recommend that you add some sheet restrictions as shown in the comments.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getsheet();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  if(col==3 && row==4){//Page Restrictions Added: if(sh.getName()=='sheetname' && col==3 && row==4){
    sh.getRange(4,12).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy/MM/dd"));
  }
}
```

- [Edit Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Get Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)
- [RangeGetSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet)
- [Javascript Basic - A Beginning Point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) Read it until you understand it.  It may take a while.  I'm still reading it.